# Como reutilizar uma interface, porém com as propriedades opcionais?

Tags: typescript, tipagem, interface

Eu possuo a seguinte interface:

```
interface User {
    id: string;
    username: string;
    password: string;
    accountId: string
  }
}
```

Eu preciso reutilizá-la, porém com as propriedades sendo opcionais. Como faço para atingir esse resultado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para criar um tipo baseado em outro, mas com **todos os campos sendo opcionais**, ou seja, campo com um valor qualquer ou `undefined`, podemos utilizar o tipo utilitário [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype).

Veja um exemplo baseado na interface `User`:

```
interface User {
    id: string;
    username: string;
    password: string;
    accountId: string
}

type OtherUser = Partial<User> 
// ou 
// interface OtherUser extends Partial<User> {}
```

<sub>[Veja no TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChkHLAAmAXMumFKAOYDc%20hArplCHALYTmXUj2MCABzjp0AdwD2UMhSq0GhZIgSSm4AJKzetXAF9cuMAE8hKAPJgAFtAxYAvMgAKcKGGBwANgB47UAHyGQA)</sub>

No exemplo acima, o tipo `OtherUser` vai ser o seguinte:

```
type OtherUser = {
    id?: string | undefined;
    username?: string | undefined;
    password?: string | undefined;
    accountId?: string | undefined;
}
```

Logo, todos os campos passaram a ser opcionais.

Não se esqueça que, para trabalhar com esses campos, as tratativas para campos opcionais devem ser tomadas. Exemplo:

```
interface User {
    id: string;
    username: string;
    password: string;
    accountId: string
}

type OtherUser = Partial<User>

const otherUser: OtherUser = {
  id: 'any'
}

console.log(otherUser.id?.toUpperCase())
```

No log, `otherUser.id?.toUpperCase` temos que usar o *Optional Chaining* `?` no campo `id` para evitar erros.

Answer (score 0):

Vc pode reaproveitar a interface utilizando o **extends** para herdar da interface pai e o **Omit** para  reescrever os atributos(propriedades).

Ex.:

```
interface User {
    id: string;
    username: string;
    password: string;
    accountId: string
  }

interface User2 extends Omit<User, "id">{
    id?: string;
}
```

Eu acredito que o mais ideal é escrever a interface de maneira que vc não precise ficar alterando a condição de cada atributo de obrigatório para opcional. Tente entender melhor o contexto da situação pra depois implementar seu código, pq talvez nem seja necessário fazer isso.